# How to wait a QueryDocumentSnapshot.docs.forEach ends to return

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

I'm using Firestore to get all documents from a collection. I want wait all docs returns from database to return a function. This return must be a array of the documents getted from collection. At the moment my console just print a `Promise` variable.

```
var getUsersSnapshot = async function() {
        var db = firebase.firestore()
        const usersSnapshot = await firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .get();
        var users = []
        await usersSnapshot.docs.forEach(element => {
            users.push(element.data())            
        });
        return users
}

var getMonthlyByUserId = function () {
    var users = getUsersSnapshot()
    console.log(users)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve()
    })
}
```

The value wrote on console is:

[image]

On the console I can see the Promise, but I expected the array of values.

Answer (score 1):

Since `getUsersSnapshot` is an `async` function, you need to use `await` when calling it.

```
var getMonthlyByUserId = async function () {
    var users = await getUsersSnapshot()
    console.log(users)
    return users;
}
```

The whole construct with the `Promise` you do seems unnecessary, since the return value is already promisified.

---

Your `getUsersSnapshot` looks unusual to me. I'd typically expect to see that written like:

```
var getUsersSnapshot = async function() {
    const usersSnapshot = await firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection("users")
        .get();
    var users = usersSnapshot.docs.map(element => element.data());
    return users
}
```

Comment: I think in your example code you should use map to assign to users, not forEach; i.e. `return usersSnapshot.docs.map(({data}) => data)`.  forEach would actually return undefined no?

Comment: Good catch! I forgot to change the method name, but did change its body. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Frank, thanks for good answer. This code is a piece of a module (Service) `.js` used inside a Vue component on `watch: { immediate: true, handler() { // Service.getMonthlyByUserId() } }` hook, since I use `async` on `getMonthlyByUserId()`, this method is not called on the Vue component. I don't know the reason yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `then()` to get the value from the `Promise`:

```
var getMonthlyByUserId = function () {
    getUsersSnapshot().then((values) =>{
   console.log(values);
 });    
}
```